# WinAPI Threadpool

Tags: c++, winapi

I've searched in google, but cannot find how can I add my own function to Threadpool. I have a function with signature `void MyFunction(void *param);`. How I can create Threadpool and add this function for assynchronos execution. I know that exist `TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback()` function, but I cannot understand how to use it. I'll be very glad to see simple example.

Comment: `TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback` doesn't look that difficult to use, but for the callback your function signature is not appropriate.

Comment: @ta.speot.is how can I add my function to winapi threadpool in easiest way. i need only to execute it assynchonosely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use `TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback` you should change signature of your function to

```
void CALLBACK MyFunction( PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE Instance, void* Context );
```

And then you can use it without problem. Remember that in windows most callbacks should have the `CALLBACK` in their definition, because default calling convention in C is `__cdecl` but in Windows API it is usually `__stdcall`(read it `CALLBACK`).

Comment: Thanks for reply!Imagine that i've ghanged signature, and how can i add this function to threadpool.